# Leverage local state and avoid fetching data when data is already available?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, local-storage, redux-saga

I currently have a couple of api's fetching data, which in turn require data from a previous api for the following api's to fetch necessary data, depending on the interaction and route. At the moment I have all this tied in and working well with my reducers and actions. But, I'm wondering how I can I conditionally fetch data depending on wether the local state is already available or not?

My ideal solution would be to leverage local state once a user loads the data the first time and not have to keep fetching data on their initial instance. I've seen many examples of pulling data in from api's, but nothing that gives an example of using local data (already fetched) for performance reasons, vs having to call an api each time then person renders the component / page.

What is the best approach for tackling this situation?

This is what I have so far and was wondering if this is a good approach?

`idea.sagas.js`

```
function shouldFetchIdeas() {
  const state = store.getState();
  if (!state.idea.ideas) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

export function* fetchIdeas({ payload: organizationId }) {
  if (shouldFetchIdeas()) {
    try {
      const fetchApi = yield axios(
        `https://api.getconflux.com/api/v1/public/${organizationId}/ideas`
      );
      yield put(fetchIdeasSuccess(fetchApi.data.rows));
    } catch (error) {
      yield put(fetchIdeasFailure(error.message));
    }
  }
}


export function* onFetchIdeasStart() {
  yield takeLatest(IdeasActionTypes.FETCH_IDEAS_START, fetchIdeas);
}

export function* ideaSagas() {
  yield all([call(onFetchIdeasStart)]);
}
```

This currently works, but it feels dirty. I have around 3-4 api calls and what I've shown you above is an example. Is there an alternative, or a right way to leverage local state without having to fetch the data everytime?

Anyways, would be great to hear your thoughts or if there is a better way of managing this or if you could direct me to any solutions out there or any examples.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question is likely to be closed, as it doesn't have a clear problem statement. You also don't give any background on the scale of the problem, and why this is an issue for you

Comment: https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist might help you

Comment: @imjared I have persist already built in, but i keep fetching data from the api regardless. When there isn't any need to once you've already fetched it. For example if I move into a new route then go back, it will refetch the data, instead of using what we've already loaded. I'd love to just use local state after the first initial fetch, then manipulate the state for different interactions.

Comment: @Sananes - why would you want to fetch ideas again? if you fetched them at the beginning you can use `redux` to manage them without fetching them again

Comment: @jank sorry for not being clear. That’s exactly what I was referring to. Not having to fetch data again. Fetch it once and then just use global app state. But my issue is every time I change route and visit the page that displays the (already fetched data) it fetches vs using what’s available in global app state. I just wanted to know if there’s a particular best practice way of doing it. So far all I’ve done is a function to see if data is already available And if it is, don’t fetch.

Comment: @Sananes - mmm ok, now I get you... you don't need to check if the data is available. All you need to do is passing the data into the component you are routing to as props. Then, you'll have the data available, instead of fetching it again in the component.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using local state instead of fetching data again in order to update your local state and as a result the view. This is one among other things which frameworks like `redux` trying to achieve.

To do that, use a container component that fetches all the necessary data and passes it into sub-components in each route:

```
class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.actions.getTrailers();
        this.props.actions.getCharacters();
        this.props.actions.getFavorites();
    }

    render() {  
        return (
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/characters">
                    <Characters characters={characters} />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/favorites">
                    <Favorites favorites={favorites} />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/trailers">
                    <Trailers trailers={trailers} />
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        }
    }
}
```

Inside each sub-component, you can use `redux` selectors to access other component's data. For example `<Trailers />` can access `favorites` and `characters` via selectors, or use its own props to get his dedicated piece of data (i.e: `trailers`).

This practice reduce redundant API calls and helps you keep your network tab clean in the dev tools. Moreover, it will help sub-component to render faster since you have already pre-fetched their data.

Further, think of how you can manage the same practice over CRUD operations. Each operation also require API call. You can handle them inside the reducers and avoid fetching the data again for each operation. Doing so will keep your app responsive.

Redux keeps your state unless you hit refresh, then you need `redux-persist`.

Hope it helps, I might update this answer as it might need further clarification.

Comment: That makes total sense! Thanks a bunch for the explanation. Really appreciate it my man!

Comment: here's another question. I have two routes. Overview of `ideas` and `idea` detail page. The individual idea needs to be fetched separately, the overview itself doesn't as it's already been fetched. The problem is, if I visit the `idea` individual detail page directly, then it still wants to fetch `ideas` as its part of its container. How do I prevent this from happening?

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/" ideas={ideas}>Ideas overview</Route>
  <Route path="/:ideaId">Idea detail</Route> // This particular route doesn't need to fetch ideas data
</Switch>
```

Comment: @Sananes - isn't `idea` part of `ideas`? I am asking this in order to understand the structure of the data coming from your endpoint, and also, to know if there is a reason for you to fetch `idea` separately.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's how the api is structured. Individual idea posts contain much more data, so its a separate fetch. We have `ideas` which is a list of all ideas a company has, then we have the individual `idea` items which provide more detail. Hopefully, thanks makes more sense! Thanks for all this @jank

Comment: @Sananes - so there are two components that should fetch different data in their `componentDidMount()`:
1.)`<Ideas />` - should fetch initial `ideas` (for overview).
2.)`<Idea id={idea.id} />` - should fetch an `idea` with a given id as a prop.
Routing shouldn't cause a re-render of the container component, can you verify that flow?
Note: If you are redirecting to `<idea />` from another component then it will cause re-render for that component.